# vba excel cell= sum of column of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Would like VBA Excel to populate a cell in current file, with the sum of a column from another workbook.  Specific column can be different lengths in future.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can reference different workbooks and perform a sum of a column.  Obviously you will have to tweak it if you want to make it dynamic or loop through columns.  But you get the idea.

```
Sub test()


Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")


wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Application.Sum(wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1))



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a version of this, but not exactly.  I realize now, that the result is the total column without taking Filters into consideration.  Any way to get the column total of filtered data?  by the way, another column holds the filtering.  Thank you.